# induce error for debugging purposes?

Tags: actionscript-3, error-handling

Hypothetically, I have a switch that has 437 cases. I've identified every possible case (I think), and each is handled.
I'm worried that I missed # 438, and want something in the Default to alert me of this.
I could put a

```
trace("ERROR! Stackoverflow has detected your ginormous gaffe and suspended your account indefinitely!");
```

in there, but I'm worried that this error will occur 7 weeks from now and the trace will be lost among all of my other silly warning traces. I've considered having my Default do this:

```
trace(myArray[-1]);
```

which would surely(?) give an error and stop the program, alerting me to my hideous oversight, but am wondering if there isn't some better, smarter way to go about detecting a possible error like this.
Anyone? Bueller?

Comment: I would be more worried about 437 cases in a switch statement...  But to throw an error – divide by 0 is always reliable.

Comment: Devision by 0 will give you Infinity, no error would be thrown :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not to throw an error?

```
default: 
    throw new Error("Default reached");
```

Comment: See?!? I **knew** there was a better, smarter way to do it! :) "The gun won't fire if you don't have any bullets, yer honour!"

Comment: @Chowzen, if this Answer works then mark as solved by ticking the `✔` icon.

Answer (score 3):

The first option is to throw an exception:

```
throw new Error('Exception!!!')
```

but you wont get anything if you don't have debugger flashplayer

Another way is to show a popup:
In case you use flashplayer in browser:

```
ExternalInterface.call("alert", "Exception!!!");
```

In case you use Flex Framework:

```
Alert.show('Exception!!!')
```

You could try to highlite it somehow:

```
trace(  "==========================================\n" + 
        "==========================================\n" +
        "==========================================\n" +
        "===============Exception!!!===============\n" + 
        "==========================================\n" +
        "==========================================\n" +
        "==========================================\n" +);
```

And the last option is a custom popup:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

const theStage:Stage = MovieClip(root).stage;
const tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.text = "Exception!!!";
tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
tf.x = theStage.stageWidth - tf.width  >> 1;
tf.y = theStage.stageHeight - tf.height  >> 1;
tf.border = true;
tf.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent){
    e.currentTarget.parent.removeChild(e.currentTarget);
})
theStage.addChild(tf);
```